# sed substitution subexpress system call in python

Tags: python, replace, sed, system-calls

I don't known if it is a python bug or something else.

I have a bash command to get the br0 IP address. It works well in the bash shell

```
$ip -o -4 address show br0 |  sed "s/^.*inet *\(.*\)\/[0-9]* brd.*$/\1/g"
$192.168.10.1  #output this
```

But onece I combine it with python, it gives me a weird result:

```
>>>import commands as c 
>>>c.getstatusoutput('ip -o -4 address show br0 |  sed "s/^.*inet *\(.*\)\/[0-9]* brd.*$/\1/g"')

>>>(0, '\x01')  #output
```

I have tried PHP with `system()` and it works fine. I have also tried the subprocess in python and the result is the same.

Could it be a pipe handling problem in python?

I want to know what happened in python, or if there is something else I've missed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Python is interpreting the backslashes in your string, try using a raw string, ie. `r'ip -o -4 address show br0 |  sed "s/^.*inet *\(.*\)\/[0-9]* brd.*$/\1/g"'`

```
>>> import commands as c 
>>> c.getstatusoutput(r'ip -o -4 address show br0 |  sed "s/^.*inet *\(.*\)\/[0-9]* brd.*$/\1/g"')
```

And if you are curious, try this and note the difference:

```
>>> print "s/^.*inet *\(.*\)\/[0-9]* brd.*$/\1/g"
s/^.*inet *\(.*\)\/[0-9]* brd.*$//g
>>> print r"s/^.*inet *\(.*\)\/[0-9]* brd.*$/\1/g"
s/^.*inet *\(.*\)\/[0-9]* brd.*$/\1/g
```

[The problem is that python treats "\1" as the string '\x01']